# Error converting images from png to gif in Node.js

Tags: node.js

**When converting png to gif to upload images in gif format
An error message is given from the server and then it restarts**

```
if (aadrit.query.state == "user") {
              Jimp.read("uploads/" + LinkUpload + "/" + aadrit.file.filename, (toshiko, mythri) => {
                if (toshiko) {
                  ayriana.end(JSON.stringify({
                    err: true,
                    msg: ""
                  }));
                  return;
                } else {
                  fs.unlink("uploads/" + LinkUpload + "/" + aadrit.file.filename, kharli => {
                    if (kharli) {
                      ayriana.end(JSON.stringify({
                        err: true,
                        msg: ""
                      }));
                      return;
                    }
                    ;
                  });
                  mythri.write("uploads/" + LinkUpload + "/" + 
                  aadrit.file.filename.replace(aadrit.file.filename, aadrit.query.state == "user" ? 
                  aadrit.hostname + "pic.png" : 
                  aadrit.hostname + aadrit.query.state + ".png"));
                }
                ;
              });
```

## وهذه رسالة الخطأ

```
 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Promise
```

**What is the appropriate way to upload images in gif format?**

I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).